# How to execute bulk of queries in mysql using php more efficiently?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a csv file. In my PHP script I am reading this csv file row wise (saving each column in an array) and then performing some operations on any specific column value (like finding timestamp of a date and time column). After this processing I am inserting these values and some of the values read from csv file into mysql tables.

I have 4 tables in which I have to insert and some tables required multiple insertion for a single row. In my case I am performing at least 6 inserts for a single row.

I want to know is there any efficient way to achieve this so that I can increase performance of my PHP script.Right now I am performing all insertions alone means executing 1 insert statement for 1 insert operation. It is taking a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: Start by adding your current code. So we can see what can be improved / modified to help you in your problem.

Comment: Are the insertions on the same table? You can send multiple value inserts
Aren't they? Perhaps you should check mysqli and mysqli_statement for speeding up queries

Comment: @Olvathar yes your suggestion is correct. using string concatenation now i am executing only 4 insert queries(4 tables) and it take only fraction of second. Thanks a lot